# SQL Query Improvement - Picking X only if A>B where A and B values are within a scope range of a variable

Tags: mysql, sql

I am practicing my SQL skills and trying to solve some exercises.

**Problem:** For all cases where the same reviewer rated the same movie twice (**stored in rating table**) and gave it a higher rating (**rating.stars**) the second time, return the reviewer's name (**stored in reviewer table**) and the title of the movie (**stored in movie table**).

```
SELECT 
    r.NAME AS reviewer
    ,m.Title AS movietitle  
FROM rating ra
LEFT JOIN movie m ON m.mID = ra.mID
LEFT JOIN reviewer r ON r.rID = ra.rID
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        ra.rID
        ,ra.mID
        ,MAX(ra.RatingDate) AS MaxDate
        ,MIN(ra.RatingDate) AS MinDate
        ,MAX(ra.stars) AS MaxStars
        ,MIN(ra.stars) AS MinStars
    FROM Rating ra
    GROUP BY ra.rID, ra.mID
    HAVING MAX(ra.stars) <> MIN(ra.stars) and COUNT(*) = 2
) rs ON ra.rID = rs.rID AND ra.mID = rs.mID
WHERE 
    ra.Ratingdate = rs.MaxDate 
    AND ra.stars = rs.MaxStars
```

For the above query solution I tried and is **correct** (I think)

1. Is this the most clear way for solving the problem?
2. Are there any shortcuts for solving the same problem?
3. What is the practical name of these problems? I made out a name on my title as "Picking X only if A>B where A and B values are within a scope range of a variable". Is there a better way to categorize those type of problems or are they already categorized within books or in communities of some sort?

*References*

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8031b/1509

http://i42.photobucket.com/albums/e311/indiecoding/data_zpsd505fa8a.png

Comment: +1 for preparing the question well, including SQL fiddle.

Comment: I don't think your query is correct. The problem says that the later rating is higher than the earlier rating. You're just testing whether he gave it different ratings, which might be the second rating being _lower_ than the first. To get the specific results in the problem, you need to use a self-join of the `ratings` table.

Comment: I take that back. Your final `WHERE` clause solves that problem. Although it should actually be in the `ON` clause, since it's comparing two tables/subqueries.

Comment: I would still recommend a self-join, as it generalizes better. Your query won't work for people who rated something 3 times.

Comment: If you have working code, and are looking for comments on the style and suggestions for improvement, codereview.stackexchange.com is a better place for it.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning codereview.stackexchange. I was wondering Barmar how I could make the answer shorter, it is just a simple exercise in the book so I was wondering. Self joins do the trick :). For more than 3 times, I could imagine use row number with partition and ranking along with derived tables. Have the habit of using derived tables cause it is easier to visualize but it does not look hard with the answers I got bellow. Thanks for all the help you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be inclined to do this with an `exists` clause:

```
select rv.name, m.title
from rating r join
     movie m
     on r.mid = m.mid join
     reviewer rv
     on r.rid = rv.rid
where exists (select 1
              from rating r2
              where r2.rid = r.rid and
                    r2.mid = r.mid and
                    r2.ratingdate < r.ratingdate and
                    r2.stars < r.stars
             );
```

The `join`s just bring the necessary tables together to get the reviewer name and movie name.  The key is the correlated subquery.  It directly implements the logic you are looking for.

Comment: this is much cleaner.

Comment: +1 and selected as accepted answer for using 1. "exists" (this is new to me) 2. putting on the where clause which makes it more clear 3. Using lesser instead of greater operators which will bring the same result for this case, I did not thought about that.

Question though: would it be a bottleneck in performance if I replaced where exists... to "inner join rating sj ON r.rid = sj.rid and r.mid = sj.mid and r.ratingdate < sj.ratingdate and r.stars < sj.stars"?

Comment: @stacktogo . . . For your data, switching to an `inner join` should be very similar performance-wise.  The advantage of `exists` is that it can stop at the first matching value.  This would be a bigger difference when reviewers reviewed the same movie many times.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Stops at the first matching value, very interesting. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This will generate one row per pair pod ratings that qualify. i.e., if there are three ratings by same reviewer for same movie, with increasing ratings, you will get one row in output for each pair (1,2);  (2, 3), and (1,3).  Of course, the movie name and rater name will be the same for all output rows anyway, so if that's all you want, then just add a distinct to the select clause and you'll only get one row...

```
Select r.Name reviewer, m.Title movietitle  
From rating r1
  join rating r2 
     On r2.mID = r1.mID
       And rID = r1.rID
       And r2.RatingDate > r1.RatingDate
       And r2.stars > r1.stars
  left join movie m ON m.mID = r1.mID
  left join reviewer r ON r.rID = 1.rID
```

If you don't want to see the output for (1, 3) [where there is an intervening rating between the two], and if you want other data to be generated like the rating dates, for example, then that would require use of a subquery to restrict pairings to adjacent (successive) ratings...

```
Select r.Name reviewer, m.Title movietitle  
From rating r1
  join rating r2 
     On r2.mID = r1.mID
       And rID = r1.rID
       And r2.stars > r1.stars
       And r2.RatingDate =
           (Select min(ratingDate)
            From rating 
            Where mID = r1.mId
              and rId = r1.rId
              And ratingDate > r1.ratingDate)
  left join movie m ON m.mID = r1.mID
  left join reviewer r ON r.rID = 1.rID
```

Comment: Let me paraphrase: r2.RatingDate > r1.RatingDate can bring more than one result (i.e. Date2 > Date1 & Date3 > Date1), thus records out of successive iteration.

Thus, having r1 the "next iterative" date already, we are solid sure that r2.RatingDate=r1.NextIterativeDate will bring only one result and all the successive iterations will be sorted by r2.stars > r1.stars

Wow, that is really good! +1 for the extra effort and mentioning self joins which I did not thought about it. Unfortunately, have to give the star more related to my question. Awesome answer, grasped it yet with my short vision.